# Overlay face with javascript screen recording then save it?

Tags: javascript

I am making a screen recorder in JavaScript. I got the code that I have so far from https://dev.to/sebastianstamm/screen-recording-in-10-lines-of-vanilla-js-3bo8.

Is there any way to record the face, then overlap the video of the user's face with the screen recording, and save it in a .webm file?
The full code from the post that I found is this:

```js
const start = document.getElementById("start");
const stop = document.getElementById("stop");
const video = document.querySelector("video");
let recorder, stream;

async function startRecording() {
  stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
    video: { mediaSource: "screen" }
  });
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  const chunks = [];
  recorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
  recorder.onstop = e => {
    const completeBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: chunks[0].type });
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(completeBlob);
  };

  recorder.start();
}

start.addEventListener("click", () => {
  start.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  stop.removeAttribute("disabled");

  startRecording();
});

stop.addEventListener("click", () => {
  stop.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  start.removeAttribute("disabled");

  recorder.stop();
  stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
});
```

And the HTML:

```html
<button id="start">
      Start Recording
    </button>
    <button id="stop" disabled>
      Stop Recording
    </button>
    <video autoplay />
```

Comment: how do you envision this looking? The user's face is in the corner? Or the user's background is stripped out and replaced with their desktop?

Comment: The users face in the corner.

Answer (score 0):

You can record webcam footage (example [here](https://blog.addpipe.com/mediarecorder-api/)), and along the same lines record screen footage. How you combine them is trickier, I think. Simplest is to download the separate feeds as two different files and combine them with something like `ffmpeg` or any video editor. Otherwise you could maybe play with the canvas (like [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Manipulating_video_using_canvas)), or maybe some third party Javascript library has already done that work for you.